# Usage of checkbox to retrive the multiple dataitems in Datagrid inASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   foreach (DataGridItem di in GridView1.Items)
   {
       HtmlInputCheckBox chkBx = (HtmlInputCheckBox)di.FindControl("CheckBox1");
       if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
       {
          //What should I write to get the Items of that checked row.

       }
     }

   }
```

Help me how to retrieve the row items of the each checked row.

I tried like this but its not appending anything to the label

```
      foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
   {
       HtmlInputCheckBox chkBx = (HtmlInputCheckBox)di.FindControl("CheckBox1");
       if ( chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
       {
           FID[j] += di.Cells[2].Text;
           j++;

           Label1.Text += di.Cells[2].Text;

            }

       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should `Rows` instead `Items`

```
foreach (GridViewRow di in GridView1.Rows)
{
   HtmlInputCheckBox chkBx = (HtmlInputCheckBox)di.FindControl("CheckBox1");
   if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
   {
      //What should I write to get the Items of that checked row.

   }
 }
```

Comment: Its giving error at HtmlinputCheckBox what should I use there I have asp:CheckBox type Template.

Comment: namespace or type HtmlInputCheckBox is not found.

Comment: did you add this using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls; ?

Comment: In the if condition I want that row items how can I do that?

Comment: You have to find control from the row object.

Comment: what's the issue, better to post it new question.

Comment: Are you getting text di.Cells[2].Text; ?

Comment: When I click the button the page is refreshing and nothing is appending to checkbox and chexkbox values also clearing.

Comment: You might be rebinding the gridview in page load

Comment: How to stop page_load on button click?